# Storing a double to use throughout if statements

Tags: java, loops

I'm a beginner programmer and have been playing around with this for a few days now... I cannot seem to find a way to store a double run it through a series of if statements then display that double in a `System.out.println("...")`.

I have tried using arrays, switches, etc. There is a lot more I need to run this BaseRate through, depending on the users input I need to modify the BaseRate and have it store the previous modification.

The closest I have come up with is storing the BaseRate through a couple of if statements but the end result still ends up as the original number (4000.00). I really don't know the language very well, it's tough programming when you don't know much of the language and its possibilities. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class example 
{
public static double BaseRate = 4000.00; //really not familiar with this
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner( System.in);
    double BaseRate2 = BaseRate; //probably not necessary
//Name
            System.out.println("\rPlease enter your name:");
            String UserName = keyboardInput.nextLine();
//Gender
            System.out.println("Are you male or female? Answer m or f:");
            String input;
            char UserSex;
            input = keyboardInput.nextLine();
            //If the applicant is female, apply a 5 % discount to the base rate.
            UserSex = input.charAt(0);
            if (UserSex == 'f')
                {
                    System.out.println("Discount 5%");
                    double BaseRate = BaseRate2 * 0.95;
                    System.out.println(BaseRate);
                }
            else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Rate is now " + BaseRate);
                }
//Experience Driving
            System.out.println("How many years have you been driving?");
            int UserExperience = keyboardInput.nextInt();
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            //If driving more than one year and less than 5, 
            //then apply a 5% discount for each year of driving.
            //----------------------------------------------------------------
            if ( UserExperience == 0 )
            {
                System.out.println("No Discount");
            }
            else if ( UserExperience < 5 )
                {
                    System.out.println("Discount 5% per year");
                    double BaseRate = BaseRate2 -  ((UserExperience * 0.05)* BaseRate2);
                    System.out.println(BaseRate);
                }
//Quote
                System.out.println(UserName + " , your rate is a follows:");
                System.out.println(BaseRate); //here is the issue

}

}
```

The problem is the final //quote the BaseRate is unmodified and stays at 4000.0
I really do not want to have to put in a new variable name for each possibility (since there are more than just "m or f" as well as "experience driving". I need a way of having a variable change throughout if statements depending on the users input to stay as that number (not return like this one wants too). This stuff should be so simple... I'm just getting really frustrated!

Answer (score 3):

> The closest I have come up with is storing the BaseRate through a couple of if statements

The trouble is that in those `if` statements you're redeclaring `BaseRate` as a local variable:

```
if (UserSex == 'f')
{
    System.out.println("Discount 5%");
    double BaseRate = BaseRate2 * 0.95;
    System.out.println(BaseRate);
}
```

That doesn't change the value of the *static* variable at all... and the value of the local variable is effectively useless when the variable falls out of scope at the end of the block.

Just change code like that to assign a new value to the existing variable:

```
if (UserSex == 'f')
{
    System.out.println("Discount 5%");
    BaseRate = BaseRate2 * 0.95;
    System.out.println(BaseRate);
}
```

Alternatively, remove the static variable entirely, and declare a local variable within the method before all of the `if` blocks - it's not clear why you'd want static variables at all here.

Additionally, I'd suggest you use a more conventional bracing style and use camelCase for your variable names.

Comment: yeah I should be using CamelCase and thanks, I do not need a static variable, the problem all came down to was using the double in front of baseRate, thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the local declarations of `BaseRate` to set the variable at class level:

```
double BaseRate = BaseRate2 * 0.95;
```

change to:

```
BaseRate = BaseRate2 * 0.95;
```

Similarly here:

```
BaseRate = BaseRate2 - ((UserExperience * 0.05) * BaseRate2);
```

Comment: That really pisses me off that it was so simple... thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the variable `BaseRate` in multiple places, in different scopes. For example:

```
double baserate = 4000.00D;

{ // inner scope
     double baserate = 1.0D
     System.out.println(baserate);
}

System.out.println(baserate);
```

will print out 1.0, then 4000.0, because inside the block `{}` you have temporarily redefined `baserate`. This "local" declaration of `baserate` is completely independent of the outer one. When you exit the inner scope, the inner declaration is "forgotten" and you see only the outer declaration again.

"Shadowing" existing variables in this way can get very confusing and is best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new variable every time. Just use

```
BaseRate = blah blah
```

instead of

```
double BaseRate = blah blah
```